# Can mathematica achieve symbolization of geometric drawing and operations?

Tags: plotting, geometry

For example, verifying the properties of a parabola:

As shown in the following figure: For a parabola y ^ 2=2px (p>0), its focal point F and coordinates are (p/2,0). Point A (x0, y0) is on the parabola, while point A1 (- p/2, y0) is the projection of point A on the parabola's Directrix. Connect A1F to the y-axis at point P. If the intersection x-axis of AP is extended at point A2, then the quadrilateral AA1A2F is a diamond, and FP is perpendicular to AP.

[image]

The equation y ^ 2=2px (p>0) for a parabola only contains a parameter that is not a real number. Can mathematica draw an image that meets the requirements based on this equation. At the same time, the coordinate values of points F, A, A1, P, etc. are also represented by symbols. Can they be drawn into the diagram and represented by the corresponding letter symbols above. Draw a good picture and mark the corresponding coordinate values with symbols.

Can mathematica verify this property based on the coincidence value operation in the image?

Or if it is hard to calculate, it will involve a lot of knowledge of analytical geometry So, is there a WYSIWYG method?

Comment: (-1) The question is just careless. You don't even translate 准线 correctly.

Comment: 准线 (directrix) isn't the only issue at all, **for example**, what's "coincidence value operation"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$Version

(* "13.3.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (July 24, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

labels = {"F", "A", Subscript["A", 1], Subscript["A", 2], "P"};

offsets = 1.25 {{-1, 1}, {1, -1}, {1, -1}, {1, 1}, {0, -1}};

Manipulate[
 y0 = Sqrt[2*p*x0];
 pts = {{p/2, 0}, {x0, y0}, {-p/2, y0}, {-x0, 0}, {0, y0/2}};
 ∠APA1 = Pi*Round[
    TriangleMeasurement[pts[[{2, 3, 5}]], {"InteriorAngle", 3}]/Pi,
    10^-6];
 Show[
  ContourPlot[y^2 == 2*p*x,
   {x, -7, 7}, {y, -7, 7},
   Axes -> True],
  Graphics[{
    Style[Text[##], 16] & @@@ Transpose[{labels, pts, offsets}],
    Text[
     Style[StringForm["∠APA1 = ``", ∠APA1], 18], {-5, 
      6}],
    Line@Join[Most@pts, {pts[[1]]}],
    Line[pts[[{1, 3}]]],
    Line[pts[[{2, 4}]]],
    {Gray, Dashed, AbsoluteThickness[1],
     InfiniteLine[{{-p/2, y0}, {p/2, y0}}],
     InfiniteLine[{{-p/2, -1}, {-p/2, 1}}]},
    AbsolutePointSize[6], Red,
    Point[pts]}],
  ImageSize -> Large],
 {{p, 3}, 1, 5, 0.05, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{x0, 4, Subscript[x, 0]}, 1, 6, 0.05, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 SynchronousUpdating -> False,
 TrackedSymbols :> {p, x0}]
```

[image]

**EDIT:** Using [`GeometricScene`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GeometricScene.html)

```
SeedRandom[123];

scene = RandomInstance[
  GeometricScene[
   {{F, A, A1, A2, P},
    {p, x0, angle}},
   {GeometricAssertion[Line[{A, A1}], "Horizontal", "Leftward"],
    GeometricAssertion[Line[{A2, F}], "Horizontal", "Rightward"],
    GeometricAssertion[{Line[{A1, A2}], Line[{A, F}]}, "Parallel", "Downward"],
    Midpoint[Line[{A, A2}]] == P,
    Line[{A1, F}],
    EuclideanDistance[A, A1] == x0 + p/2,
    EuclideanDistance[F, A2] == x0 + p/2,
    EuclideanDistance[F, A] == EuclideanDistance[{p/2, 0}, {x0, Sqrt[2*p*x0]}],
    PlanarAngle[{A, P, A1}] == angle}]]
```

[image]

```
Round[angle /. scene["Quantities"], Pi/10^6]

(* π/2 *)
```