# Does Mathematica have geometric mapping tools and operations similar to those of Geogebra?

Tags: graphics

How to draw an image? Just draw a sketch to help us solve the problem, without writing code to draw.

Does Mathematica have geometric mapping tools and operations similar to those of Geogebra?

It works roughly like Geogebra:On the drawing layer, select the drawing buttons for ellipses, hyperbolas, parabolas, straight lines, line segments, points, etc., and on top of the drawing layer, corresponding curve images can be pulled out, making drawing very convenient. Furthermore, mathematica's symbol computing ability enables the drawn image to automatically use the corresponding curve equations and point coordinates after the corresponding coordinates are marked with symbols at the position of the point

For example, the effect of geogebra is as follows:

[image]

Comment: No, Mathematica does not have that. This is really a drawing tool. Mathematica has very basic drawing tool, if you [double click on the graphics](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/EditWolframLanguageGraphics.html).  But you can do all the above using code in Mathematica. But not using drawing tools.

Comment: [`GeometricScene`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GeometricScene.html) can do basic geometry with points, lines, circles, polygons, etc.; however, it does not appear to be able to handle curves such as parabolas and hyperbolas.

Comment: See [`update`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/288930/9362) to the answer to your previous question.